# How do I get Access Point information from a Docker container in bridged network mode?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, containers

I'm trying to collect data on the access point from a Docker container.

Normally I'd just run

```
$ iw dev wlp0s20f3 link
Connected to 8e:5a:25:a6:7f:81 (on wlp0s20f3)
        SSID: My Wifi
        freq: 2462
        RX: 2481914864 bytes (3224435 packets)
        TX: 1036520417 bytes (1800629 packets)
        signal: -54 dBm
        rx bitrate: 144.4 MBit/s MCS 15 short GI
        tx bitrate: 144.4 MBit/s MCS 15 short GI

        bss flags:      short-slot-time
        dtim period:    3
        beacon int:     100
```

parse that text and be done with it. However, my container *must* be run in bridge mode, so I don't have access to the underlying device information.

I can mount read-only volumes `/sys/class/net`, but it doesn't seem to get me all the information I need. I can mount `/proc/net/wireless`, but the interface information I care about doesn't show up.

How might I access live data from a docker container in bridge mode? Specifically I'm looking for this information:

- Current SSID
- Access Point BSSID
- Access Point link signal strength
- Total data received
- Total data transmitted
- Receive bitrate
- Transmit bitrate

Comment: So to summarize, you want to get information about your host network interface from a docker container? Well, is the container running in --privileged mode? Do you have access to host to setup a custom service?

Comment: Yes -- running in privileged mode. I do have host access, though I was hoping to not have to update the host, but can potentially do that if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try nsenter, it will execute command on the host
if container was started in privileged mode

```
/bin/bash

arg=${@}

nsenter --target 1 --mount --uts --net --ipc ${arg}
```

```
./host_cmd ip link
./host_cmd: line 1: !/bin/bash: No such file or directory
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: tap0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65520 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:8d:3c:fc:d9:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: This did not work for me, FYI